# SharePoint webhooks: Failed to validate the notification URL while creating webhook for sharepoint online list/library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, ssl, webhooks, postman

In POSTMAN while sending post request to create webhook, it returned with 400 bad request.

```
Failed to validate the notification URL 'https://ngrokfrwdURL.ngrok.io/api/spwebhook/handlerequest

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <m:code>-1, System.InvalidOperationException</m:code>
    <m:message xml:lang="en-US">Failed to validate the notification URL 'https://ngrokURL.ngrok.io/api/spwebhook/handlerequest'.</m:message> </m:error>
```

Comment: Keep your web application active during this process

Answer (score 0):

Rather I would suggest use this tool to create subscriptions for your desired list/library:

[SharePoint Framework web part to manage Webhooks](https://github.com/estruyf/spfx-webhooks-config)